Migration from Spark 3.1 to 3.3 org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException failures
Pipeline is running fine in spark 3.1 version (dataproc 2), while migrating to spark 3.3 (Dataproc 2.1), job is failing with below error.

FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(246, ---internal, 7337, None), shuffleId=4,
mapIndex=46, mapId=146341, reduceId=3728, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 30000 milliseconds (plus
99232 nanoseconds delay) for SettableFuture@44254158[status=PENDING]
24/04/03 09:56:08 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas
available for rdd_4531_8789 ! 24/04/03 09:56:08 WARN
BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for
rdd_4531_316485 ! 24/04/03 09:56:08 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:
No more replicas available for rdd_4531_107522

Same code works fine in spark 3.1 (dataproc 2)
It should work fine in new spark version as well.

No more replicas available this typically means that executor which was handling that block has errored out and caused this error. you need to dig more details into the logs. This might be caused by changes that have happened in Spark which makes your old code error out in never version of spark.

I was able to resolve that error by adding property
"spark.shuffle.service.enabled": "false"
